# Is there a way to shrink the callback of my menu button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, optimization

I'm quite new to Javascript and I'm trying to get my code more optimized.

So this is just a simple menu toggle I made and I'm wondering if there is a way to better optimize it because I kind of have almost to identical functions for handling the menu.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".open-menu").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.menu').addClass('active');
    } );

     $(".close-menu").click(function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.menu').removeClass('active');
    } );
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f4f7fc;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin-left .5s ease;
}

.active {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#close-menu" class="close-menu">Close</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About our project</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="#open-menu" class="open-menu">Open menu</a>
```

Comment: what you have is optimised i think

Comment: *"I feel like I'm missing something"*: please elaborate.

Comment: Have you considered using a ```<button type="button">``` instead of anchor elements to toggle the menu state? An anchor should be used when you need to navigate to somewhere else. You don't need this behaviour, in fact your JS code tells the browser to stop the default behaviour. A button would be much better suited for your purpose.

Comment: But isn't it hard to style a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. There are a few ways to optimize your code.

1. You have a small error in your HTML: `<li><a href="#about">About our project</li></a>`. Your closing `</a></li>` is swapped.
2. You could use a styled button instead of an anchor, so you'd be able to shrink your code even further.
3. You could change your opening and closing links to one generic class and then use `toggleClass`
4. For better performance, instead of using `margin-left` use `transform: translateX` ([here is an article about why](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/))

```js
jQuery( function( $ ) {
  $( '.menu-toggle' )
    .click( () => $( '.menu' ).toggleClass( 'active' ) );
} );
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f4f7fc;
  transform: translateX( -100% );
  transition: transform .5s ease;
}

.active {
  transform: translateX( 0 );
}

.menu-toggle {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: inherit;
  margin: inherit;
  font: inherit;
  
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><button class="menu-toggle">Close</button></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About our project</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button class="menu-toggle">Open menu</button>
```

Comment: Oh cool - I didn't know you can style a button that easily. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  t = 0;
  $(".open-menu,.close-menu").click(function(event) {
    if (t == 0) {
      t = 1;
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.menu').toggleClass('active').promise().done(function() {
        t = 0;
      })
    }
  });
});
```

`.toggleClass('active')` will add/remove the class depending on if the element has the class

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  t = 0;
  $(".open-menu,.close-menu").click(function(event) {
    if (t == 0) {
      t = 1;
      event.preventDefault();
      $('.menu').toggleClass('active').promise().done(function() {
        t = 0;
      })
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f4f7fc;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin-left .5s ease;
}

.active {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#close-menu" class="close-menu">Close</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About our project</li></a>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="#open-menu" class="open-menu">Open menu</a>
```

Comment: This will open the menu if you press close twice. Or close the menu when you click open twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly shorten this a bit. You don't have to rewrite code for each element. I modified your HTML slightly by adding a `data` attribute and a custom class `controls` that defines the menu action elements.

So I listen for a click on the `controls` class, call `preventDefault()` and then use a `ternary operator` to shorten the class toggle process.

**Here is a working fiddle:**

```js
jQuery(function($) {
 $('.controls').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    $('.menu').removeClass('active').addClass(($(this).data('action') === 'open') ? 'active' : '');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #f4f7fc;
  margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin-left .5s ease;
}

.active {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#close-menu" data-action="close" class="controls">Close</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About our project</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="#open-menu" data-action="open" class="controls">Open menu</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

***I'd keep it as you currently have it*** (apart from indenting a bit better). You have two different buttons, which do two different things. Right now, the difference is minimal, but I often connect more code to the open and close buttons, which differ between the two. It is obvious what is going on, especially compared to the more minimal version.

The other solutions result in a toggle functionallity. I'm not a big fan of that, because when you accidentally click close twice (happens more often than you think), you menu opens up again. By splitting the functions, you have more control over userinterface.